# How long does it take for an account to be unblocked after 5 failed attempts?

Tags: users

I've tried to log in unsuccessfully to Drupal and I get the following error:

> There have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked.

Does anyone know how long the waiting time is for localhost?

Comment: you can use to empty the flood table in DB and you wont need to wait

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your question:

> The amount of failed logins is recorded in the table 'flood'. You can
>   either wait before trying to login again **(6 hours)** or clean the
>   flood table with the procedure below.

Options for not having to wait:

> Execute the following query on the Drupal database:
>
> `DELETE FROM 'flood'`; If command above doesn't work try this:
>
> TRUNCATE flood RESTART IDENTITY; To execute this query it will be
>   necessary to login to the database. This is typically done through the
>   command line or through a GUI interface such as phpMyAdmin. If Drush
>   is installed on your server, the drush sql-cli command provides quick
>   access to an SQL command-line interface.
>
> From the command line, **with Drush installed**:
>
> **drush php-eval 'db_query("DELETE FROM `flood`");'** NOTE: The query
>   above will delete ALL entries in the flood table. If you want to
>   remove only a specific user's entries from the flood table, the
>   following is more specific.
>
> `DELETE FROM flood WHERE event = 'failed_login_attempt_user' AND
>   identifier LIKE '1234-%';` (where 1234 is the UID of the blocked user)

<sub>Source: [Login blocked after 5 failed login attempts](https://www.drupal.org/node/1023440)</sub>

Want to change the settings for this? You can by installing [Flood control](https://www.drupal.org/project/flood_control)

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that this is still true for Drual 9?

Answer (score -3):

You can cache clear if you are having admin login in any other browser using devel module or drush cr.
 You can also use Truncate command in php my admin for cache tables to get immediate user logins.