# "There have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked." and the flood table is empty

Tags: 9, authentication-authorization

When I try to log in as an admin user, I am getting the following error:

> There have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It
> is temporarily blocked. Try again later or request a new password.

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/263531/5147) explains that this can usually be cleared up by truncating the flood table in the database.

However, when I checked my flood table in the database with PHPMyAdmin, it was empty.

I did some further troubleshooting:

- I can log in as other users, just not the suspended user.
- I am viewing the correct database; when I registered a new user, I could see the new user's data in the database.

The user in question is an admin user account that I use to log in with for behat tests; the behat tests failed on my cloud site, so I pulled the database into my local dev environment (lando) and am now trying to give myself access to that admin account.

Comment: What you are telling seems to impossible, unless you have more than one database. For example a second in-memory database like Redis.

Comment: @4k4 Good catch, redis was at fault here.  Feel free to add an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have installed Redis the database content for caching, flooding, locking and queuing will be stored in the in-memory database and you have to look there to find this data.